# Font .woff files loaded don't correspond to the displayed styles

Tags: css, fonts

I'm trying to manually add a custom font to my localhost installation of WP, what I did so far:

- download the font (Computer Modern) from fontsquirrel in `.woff` format
- take the 4 files needed (Serif): Roman (cmunrm), Bold (cmunbx), Oblique (cmunti), Bold Oblique (cmunbi)
- put the 4 files in the folder `C:\xampp\htdocs\sitename\wp-includes\fonts\latex`
- write the following in `style.css`

CSS code

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Computer Modern";
    src: url('http://localhost/sitename/wp-includes/fonts/latex/cmunrm.woff');
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Computer Modern";
    src: url('http://localhost/sitename/wp-includes/fonts/latex/cmunbx.woff');
    font-weight: bold;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Computer Modern";
    src: url('http://localhost/sitename/wp-includes/fonts/latex/cmunti.woff');
    font-style: italic, oblique;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Computer Modern";
    src: url('http://localhost/sitename/wp-includes/fonts/latex/cmunbi.woff');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic, oblique;
}
body {
    font-family: "Computer Modern", serif;
}
```

- write the following in the WP editor

HTML code

```
This is normal text
<strong>This is bold text</strong>
<em>This is oblique text</em>
<em><strong>This is bold and oblique text</strong></em>
```

but the result is this

[image]

It seems that only Bold and Oblique have been loaded, in fact by replacing `cmunti` with `cmunrm` (Oblique with Roman) and `cmunbi` with `cmunbx` (Bold Oblique with Bold) in the CSS file this is showed

[image]

What is this due to, and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why but this solved the problem

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Computer Modern";
    src: url('http://localhost/sitename/wp-includes/fonts/latex/cmunrm.woff');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Computer Modern";
    src: url('http://localhost/sitename/wp-includes/fonts/latex/cmunti.woff');
    font-style: italic;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Computer Modern";
    src: url('http://localhost/sitename/wp-includes/fonts/latex/cmunbx.woff');
    font-weight: bold;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Computer Modern";
    src: url('http://localhost/sitename/wp-includes/fonts/latex/cmunbi.woff');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}
```